# div + li random and slide (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, list, random

I am looking to display a random block with inside, also display a random `<li>` and slide. It is difficult to explain, but here is my html code : http://jsfiddle.net/LeG3nDz/za2v9/

I want my class "slide" appears randomly and inside, I also display `<li>` which is random and changes every 3s.

```
<div class="slide">
    <h1>My title</h1>
    <ul>
        <!-- RANDOM <li> -->
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain better `I want my class slide appears randomly and inside`

Comment: Do you have some JavaScript / jQuery? You got to at least try. We are not going to give it. To lead the way, you could search for jQuery slideshows and JavaScript's `Math.random`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this random plugin, I wrote:

```
$.fn.random = function(count) {
    if (count === this.length) {
        return this;
    } else if (count === undefined || count === 1) {
        return $(this[Math.round(Math.random() * (this.length-1))]);
    } else {
        this.sort( function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() } );
        return this.slice(0, count);
    }
};
```

and this code

```
$('.slide').hide().random().slideDown().find('li').hide().random().slideDown();
```

Here is updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za2v9/1/)

As for random changes every 3 seconds:

```
var li =  $('.slide').hide().random().slideDown().find('li');
(function random() {
    li.hide().random().slideDown();
    setTimeout(random, 3000);
})();
```

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your help, but Sorry I board not specify, but I have my script random. The problem is random slide of <li> :( http://jsfiddle.net/LeG3nDz/za2v9/2/

Comment: @Stéphane better is to hide them all and then random select so you can use slideDown. http://jsfiddle.net/za2v9/3/

Comment: Hi :) sometimes the script plant. Is it possible to show the div and inside the li randomly?